# PHP SESSION not getting on same URL

Tags: php, session

There are two scenarios:

1. Problem without www url
   Hi When i set session in url below
   http://www.dubaimoon.com/members/login.php
   it will access in all pages with www url but when i type url without www
   session value will not access
2. Session Problem on with www url
   when i set session in url below
   http://dubaimoon.com/members/login.php
   it will access in all pages without www url but when i type url with www
   session value will not access

Comment: in your .htaccess file set a line to force users to use one way or another, not both.

Answer (score 0):

Session is only available in one domain. `www.example.com` and `example.com` is two different domains. So you have to use your .htaccess to use only `www` or `non-www` version, not both (it's also bad for SEO as google will see it as two different URLS). You can check [HERE](http://www.justinas.tk/blogger/force-users-to-use-only-site-with-www-subdomain/5) to see how to make `non-www` redirect to `www`.

Comment: Thanks for Help i really appreciate your answer.

Comment: @NadeemAhmed If my answer is good for you, please accept it. It's best "Thanks".